# Send JSON to a unix socket with golang

Tags: sockets, go, network-programming, unix-socket

I'm trying to write a golang program to control `mpv` via issuing commands to a unix socket running at `/tmp/mpvsocket`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
func main() {                                     
  c, err := net.Dial("unix", "/tmp/mpvsocket")    
  if err != nil {                                 
    panic(err)                                    
  }                                               
  defer c.Close()                                 

  _, err = c.Write([]byte(`{"command":["quit"]}`))
  if err != nil {                                 
    log.Fatal("write error:", err)                
  }                                               
}
```

This should cause mpv to quit but nothing happens.

This command can be issued via the command line to get the expected results:

```
echo '{ "command": ["quit"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

It uses `socat` to send the JSON to the socket. How can I send this to the socket using Golang?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but there is one difference between those two methods: `echo` sends a newline and your Go program doesn't.

Comment: @AndySchweig Yep that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AndySchweig in the comments above, I needed a new line after my JSON.

The fixed line:

```
  _, err = c.Write([]byte(`{"command":["quit"]}` + "\n"))
```

The full block of fixed code:

```
func main() {                                     
  c, err := net.Dial("unix", "/tmp/mpvsocket")    
  if err != nil {                                 
    panic(err)                                    
  }                                               
  defer c.Close()                                 

  _, err = c.Write([]byte(`{"command":["quit"]}` + "\n"))
  if err != nil {                                 
    log.Fatal("write error:", err)                
  }                                               
}
```

Comment: Also, check the bytes written `b, err = c.Write(...` to make sure that the whole string was sent.